# Может ли прямое дополнение быть в родительном падеже?

Tags: дополнение

В интернете популярен тест, где нужно указать фразы с прямым дополнением.

*После приговора матросы окружили Шмидта, прощались с ним.*
Автор теста считает, что прямого дополнения здесь нет.

Является ли *Шмидта* прямым дополнением? Я так понимаю, что здесь функция аналогичная винительному падежу.

Comment: Сейчас перечитал вопрос и скорее кажется, что это винительный падеж - все равно неясно тогда почему тут нет п.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямое дополнение бывает и в родительном падеже ("налили вина"), но здесь винительный (замените Шмидта на кота, будет яснее). Лишь бы не было предлога и глагол был переходным. Возможно, составитель теста мысленно заменил "окружили" на "собрались вокруг" и подумал, что это то же самое - можно только угадывать его мысли, но то другая грамматическая конструкция.

Comment: Скорее на собаку надо заменять, а не кота. :-)

Comment: "Лишь бы не было предлога и глагол был переходным." - Этого мало вообще-то, если исходить не из школьного определения. А вы какие случаи относите к прямым дополнениям, неужели только с этими двумя свойствами?

Comment: А гадать, что думал автор - это последнее дело, если не ясна первопричина ошибки. Лучше бы поинтересоваться, из какого определения прямого дополнения он исходил. Что-то мне подсказывает, что он именно тут накосячил.

Answer (score 5):

Вы об этом тесте?  Мои дети его тоже увидели.

1. Голод здесь совсем не походил на голод в деревне. (Распутин В.)
2. На плите у тети Нади стоял горячий чайник. (Распутин В.)
3. Но тут она сама стала передавать мне каждую папину фразу. (Алексин А.)
4. После приговора матросы окружили Шмидта, прощались с ним. (Паустовский К.)

Задание теста некорректное, здесь два верных ответа - № 3 и № 4.
Передавать (что?) фразу, окружили (кого?) Шмидта. Ничего не поделаешь, человеческий фактор, невнимательность. В одном тесте кто-то ошибся, а остальные сайты списали, не проверили. Вот так и в контрольных тестах бывает, лишь бы на экзамене не было, это же судьба человека.

Comment: Людмила, все проще. Автор неверно прочитал Розенталя с Валгиной.

Answer (score 2):

Все проще. Вот цитата.

> Дополнения, выраженные формами косвенных падежей с предлогами, входя в
>   словосочетания, передающие объектные отношения, могут иметь различные
>   оттенки значений. Они могут... ; могут обозначать лицо, совместно с
>   которым совершается действие: После приговора матросы окружили Шмидта,
>   прощались с ним (Пауст.).

[Валгина Н.С., Розенталь Д.Э., Фомина М.И. Современный русский язык: Учебник / Под редакцией Н.С. Валгиной. -- 6-е изд., перераб. и доп. - М.: Логос, 2002. - 528 с.](http://pedlib.ru/Books/6/0262/6_0262-411.shtml)

Но здесь говорится о косвенном дополнении при втором глаголе "прощались".
Автор же просто механически перенес этот пример в свой список.

Возможно, надо бы спросить, "В каком примере **все** дополнения прямые, нет косвенных".